# How to make stylesheets more clear & efficient?

Tags: css

So things got out of hand.

My app is nearly done, except for a few **[unanswered SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4383667/anthonygalli-com?tab=questions&sort=newest)**.

I'd like to start cleaning up my code now, starting with the stylesheets.

At first there was a method to the madness, but then I arbitrarily started putting code in one of two files: **bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss** & **attributes.css.scss**.

While ignoring these generated files:

- account_activations.css.scss
- activities.css.scss
- application.css
- comments.css.scss
- custom.css.scss
- days_missed.css.scss
- framework_and_overrides.css.scss
- notifications.css.scss
- pages.css.scss
- password_resets.css.scss
- relationships.css.scss
- scaffolds.css.scss
- sessions.css.scss
- users.css.scss.

Not asking for you to clean my code just asking for suggestions on what works for you and best practices. I couldn't find any clear enough answers for me on the web:

Should I delete these additional files or decentralize my code from the two files? And I'd also like to rename some of the classes & id's to more clearly represent what they do instead of picking arbitrary names like `.america`.

Do you have any suggestions or best practices on how to do this as well?

**bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

$body-bg:                         #fff;
$font-family-sans-serif:          'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                   45px;
$navbar-default-bg:               white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:      #446CB3;
$brand-primary:                   #000;
$jumbotron-bg:                    #FFFFFF;

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

.valuation-padding {
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}
.comment-content-padding {
  padding-top:  30px;
}

.pagination {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  .active { 
    a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #446CB3; 
    }
  }

      a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #446CB3; 
      }

}

.pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span {
    color: #446CB3;
}

//////
.padding-feed {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.float-feed {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.activities {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;

  em {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}

.comment-border {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  padding: 5px 0;
  em {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}

////////


.comments-same-line {
  display: inline-block;
}


.ad {
  width: 100%;
}


.col-xs-2 {
  float: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 9.6666666667%;
}

#two.form-control {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

body { padding-bottom: 100px; }

.bad-pad {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: .5em;
}


.label-primary {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  color: white !important;
  a {
  color: white;
}
}

.label-info {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  color: white !important;
  a {
  color: white;
}
}

.label-warning {
  background-color: #ccac00;
  color: white !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  a {
  color: white;
}
}

.label-danger {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  vertical-align: middle;
  a {
  color: white;
}
}

.badge {
  background-color: #ccac00;
  font-size: 12px
}

#red.badge {
  background-color: red;
}

.habit-space {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    display: block;
}

.shrink-center {
    padding-left: 10em;
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    display: block;
}

// Span progressbar from badge to badge
td.stretch {
    width: 350px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

// Condense badges to sit up against progressbar
td.condense-red {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    background-color: #c0392b;
}

td.condense-gold {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    background-color: #446CB3;
}

// Position progressbar in the middle and more
.progress {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

// Make progress bar's progress default blue
.progress-bar{
  background-color: #446CB3;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.h {
  display: block;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: .87em;
  margin-bottom: .4em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold; 
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-right {
  float: left;
}

.page-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.gold-standard {
  color: #ccac00;
  a {
    color: #ccac00;
  }
}

#gold-standard {
  border-color: #ccac00;
}

.btn {
  background: #446CB3;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#gold.btn {
   background: #ccac00;
}

#red.btn {
   background: #c0392b;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:active{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 36px;
  p {
    color: #a0b4f0;
  }
}

.link-jumbotron {
    a {
    color: #a0b4f0;
  }
}

.navbar { margin-bottom: 0 }

.green {
    a {
      color: #ccac00;
    }
    color: #ccac00;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.striked {
    color: red;
}

.red {
    vertical-align: center;
    a {
      color: #c0392b;
    }
    color: #c0392b;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #446CB3;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color: white;
}

.panel-default {
  border-style: none;
}

.sidebar-daddy {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #eee;
}

#sidebarheadingtop {
  padding-top: .1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#sidebarheading {
  padding-top: .1em;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#sidebarsectiontop {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0em 0em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0em 0em;
  border-style: none;
}

#sidebarsection {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}

#sidebarsectionbottom {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top-radius: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}

.center {
     text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
     font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  &:hover {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

**attributes.css.scss**

```
// Place all the styles related to the Values controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

//sidebar
.ingrain-padding {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  ul {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

.recommendations-padding {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

#tag_cloud {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .s { font-size: 10px; }
  .m { font-size: 14px; }
  .l { font-size: 18px; }
}

.stats-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.stats-right {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.blue-background {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  a {
    color: white;
  }
}

.full-blue-background {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  a {
    color: white;
  }
}

.gold-background {
  background-color: #ccac00;
  padding-left: 15px;
  a {
    color: white;
  }
}

.border-box-1 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-2 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-3 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-4 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-5 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-6 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-7 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.border-box-8 {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.count-padding {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .8em;
  padding-left: .9em;
  padding-right: .9em;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.goal-padding {
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.goalname {
  padding-top: .7em;
  padding-bottom: .7em;
  padding-right: .5em;
}

.goaldeadline {
  width: 70px;
  padding-left: .2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: .7em;
  padding-bottom: .7em;

}

#white {
  color: white;
}

.deadline_label_class {
  display: inline;
}

.quantified-horizontal {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:top;
}

.set-stat {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.set {
  width: 7%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.habits {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

// Add indenting and background to root route
.add-padding-background {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  background: #f7f7f9;
}


// Add indenting to root route
.add-padding {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.test {
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}

body  {color:black;}
.gold-standard {color:#ccac00;}

table {
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.valuation {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.goals {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.comment {
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
}

.stats {
  * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px
}
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-top: .1em;
  padding-bottom: .1em;
    a {
    color: #a0b4f0;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
}

.america {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
}

.feed-padding {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 7em;
  padding-right: 7em;
}

.feed-button-padding {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.comment-background {
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
  padding-top: .9em;
  padding-bottom: .9em;
  padding-left: .9em;
  padding-right: .9em; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.center-buttons {
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.center-buttons-feed {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.center-buttons-feed-2 {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 46%;
}

.center-buttons-feed-3 {
  margin-left: 46%;
}

.like-float {
  padding-top:  12px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


.centered {
    padding: 7px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}


.middle {
  text-align: center;
}

.category {
  float: right;
}


td {
  padding-top: .7em;
  padding-bottom: .7em;
  padding-left: .7em;
  padding-right: .7em;
}

.valuations-button {
  margin-top : -9px;
  margin-left : 10px; 
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

select {
  width: 30.1%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

// Breaks down quantifieds horizontally
.attempt {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:top;
  padding: .8em .8em .8em .8em;
}

.america1 {
  float: left;
}

.deadline {
  width: 8%
}

.goal {
  width: 70%
}

.valuations-button {
  margin-top : -9px;
  margin-left : 10px; 
}

.missed {
  text-align: right;
  color: #c0392b;
  font-weight: bold;
  clear: both;
}

.collection_check_boxes {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.committed {
  text-align: center;
}


.text_field {  
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  }

.valuations-button {
  margin-top : -9px;
  margin-left : 10px; 
}

.valuations-button {
  margin-top : -9px;
  margin-left : 10px; 
}

.sidebar {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: #E7E7E7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Thanks for your guidance!**

Comment: Oh not asking to clean my code just asking for suggestions on what works for you and best practices. I couldn't find any clear enough answers for me on the web.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realize that would cause an issue. good points! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this site was useful for proper naming conventions:

http://www.apppie.org/pages/approach/naming.html

> "Avoid presentation or location specific words in the name, like blue,
>   text-gray, or side-block. What happens when you decide to change the
>   color? The class blue is actually red?
>
> Do not use class names that describe content of an element. One day
>   you can come up with a class name like .products-list and another day
>   you notice that product list styling is well suited for listing
>   tweets. So what would you do? Re-implement .products-list to with same
>   styles but call it .tweets-list or just let tweets live inside
>   .products-list? It is better to give it abstract name like .entries
>   from the beginning.
>
> Names should be lowercase, using a dash - as a separator in a
>   multi-word class names. It's clear, readable and distinguish CSS from
>   underscore case and camel case naming.
>
> Use full descriptive words. Abbreviating a word may save you a few
>   milliseconds to type initially, but may make your code harder to read,
>   costing you more time down the road. Being consistent in this will
>   save you the time spent thinking how exactly you abbreviated a word
>   couple of months ago.
>
> Use nouns for naming objects and modules.
>
> When it comes to naming modifiers and states, use adjectives as they
>   are describing type or state of an object."

For how to organize stylesheets I'll only use bootstrap to override bootstrap and everything else will go in attributes since breaking it down into various files would create more redundancy since I use classes in more than one place.